# Python on windows, shutting down and taking a screenshot

Tags: python, windows, windows-xp

I have the following two quesions:

1 I want to be able to shutdown windows xp from python code. I am able to do that by running the following code in the python console:

```
import os

os.system("shutdown -s -f")
```

But, if i put the same code in a .py file and try to execute it,it does not work. I get the help prompt for the shutdown command.Any way to fix this ?

2 Is there any way i can take a screenshot of the current screen using python on windows ?

Thank You

Comment: Must be annoying to debug a program that shuts down the computer.

Comment: hehe..yeah :)..but im really curious why the code does not work when run as a python script

Answer (score 2):

There's some code to shutdown windows in [this message](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2008-December/008481.html) from the python-win32 list.

You can take a screen shot using PIL's [ImageGrab](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagegrab.htm) module.